# HTML+CSS structure (header+menu+aside+main+footer)

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, float

[image: HMTL]

Может кто-то пояснить как разместить блоки (Aside1,Aside2,Main,Aside3)В строку как на картинке ,только с использованием Float

Спасибо!

Comment: оберни их в 3 колонки, которые float'ом смещай

Comment: @ZaArs какие float'ы? Flexbox'ы уже давно имеют отличную поддержку.

Comment: еще скажи что ie 9 поддерживет flex box. да и float тоже верное решениею и если обратишь внимание на теги к вопросу, так указан float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сверстал для Вас макет.

Можете смотреть на реальном примере, как это можно сделать

```
https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/PMorwe?editors=1100
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body * {
    padding: 25px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.header {
    background: #913157;
}
.menu {
    margin: 10px auto 10px;
    
    background: #6E1237;
}
.aside1 {
    width: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    background: #B55B7F;
}
.aside2 {
    width: 20%;
    background: #B55B7F;
}
.aside3 {
    width: 15%;
    background: #B55B7F;
}
.main {
    margin-left: calc(20% + 10px);
    margin-right: calc(15% + 10px);
    background: #B55B7F;
    /* width: 65%; */
}
.section1 {
    background: #DB92AF;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.section2 {
    background: #DB92AF;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    HEADER
</header>

<nav class="menu">
    MENU
</nav>

<aside class="aside3 right">
    ASIDE 3
</aside>

<aside class="aside1 left clear">
    ASIDE 1
</aside>

<aside class="aside2 clearfix left">
    ASIDE 2
</aside>

<main class="main">
    MAIN CONTENT
    <section class="section1">
        SECTION 1
    </section>

    <section class="section2">
        SECTION 2
    </section>
</main>
```